# What are some good places to look for default apache startup settings in Fedora 8?

Tags: apache, fedora

I'm running a small instance of Amazon Web Service's basic Fedora 8 LAMP stack.  The default site is set up at /home/username/helloworld, but my web root of choice is at /home/username/example.com.  Problem is, when the server reboots, it starts up using the httpd.conf in /home/username/helloworld.  I have no idea where to even start looking around for this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.  It may include other files, but you can follow them and see.

If you modify this file, you can update apache:

Switch to root:
`su -`

Check config:
`service httpd configtest`

Graceful restart:
`service httpd graceful`

**Don't forget to backup!**